# How to setup URLs for static site with Ruby Rack on Heroku

Tags: ruby, static, rack

My site is [here](http://designintellection.com/).

It used to be a Django-powered blog. However I no longer update it so I just wanted to make it a static HTML site. I wget'ed it and moved it to Heroku with Ruby Rack.

However every URL resolves to the home page. This is because of my config.ru file:

```
use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/media/images", "/media/js", "/media/css"],
  :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200, 
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

**Question:** Is there a way to map multiple URLs? e.g. `foo.com/about` maps to `public/about/index.html`, `foo.com/posts/2012/oct/21/blog-post`maps to `public/posts/2012/oct/21/blog-post/index.html`

At this point I'd even be fine typing each one by hand.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For now I found the best answer to be:

```
use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/media/images", "/media/js", "/media/css"],
  :root => "public"

map "/" do
  run lambda { |env|
  [
    200, 
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
end

map "/portfolio" do
  run lambda { |env|
  [
    200, 
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
    },
    File.open('public/portfolio/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
end
```

And map every URL to its respective file. Tedious, but works. See also the answer to [this question regarding URL variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225343/rack-how-do-you-store-the-url-as-a-variable). Couldn't get it to work for me though.

Comment: In this case, i suggest you use a wrapper like `sinatra`, which should enable you to clean your code up quite a bit.

Answer (score 7):

Why do you need the `run` statement? Maybe this works for you:

```
use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/media/images", "/media/js", "/media/css"],
  :root => "public",
  :index => "index.html",
  :header_rules => [
    [:all, {'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'}]
  ]

run lambda{ |env| [ 404, { 'Content-Type'  => 'text/html' }, ['404 - page not found'] ] }
```

Comment: Apparently you need `run`. Here's the output I got when I used the code above:
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:129:in `to_app': missing run or map statement (RuntimeError)
     from /[my local directory]/config.ru:1

Comment: Well the problem with your code is, that you catch all succesful requests with your run statement. I did not think of the case where you have no `run` statement at all. Try my edited answer.

Comment: Hmmm. That didn't seem to work either. Every page but the home page threw a 404. Thanks for your help so far by the way.

Comment: I threw together an example project for you, maybe this helps: http://github.com/padde/rack-static-example

Comment: If you are still facing problems, please append your log output to the original question.

Comment: I found an acceptable solution that I've posted as the answer. It's not optimal though. It would be great to implement it as answered in [this question about URL variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225343/rack-how-do-you-store-the-url-as-a-variable), but alas that didn't work for me. Again, thanks for answering my questions.

Comment: Strange, it worked perfectly for me. I am using Ruby 1.9.3p194 with Rack 1.1 (Release: 1.4). What versions are you using? (`ruby -v` and `rackup -v`) How are you starting the server?