# Rack: How do you store the URL as a variable?

Tags: ruby, rack

I am writing a simple static Rack app.  Check out the config.ru code below:

```
use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/elements", "/img", "/pages", "/users", "/css", "/js"],
  :root => "archive"


map '/' do
  run Proc.new { |env|
    [
      200, 
      {
        'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
        'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=6400' 
      },
      File.open('archive/splash.html', File::RDONLY)
    ]
  }
end

map '/pages/search.html' do
  run Proc.new { |env|
    [
      200, 
      {
        'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
        'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=6400' 
      },
      File.open('archive/pages/search.html', File::RDONLY)
    ]
  }
end

map '/pages/user.html' do
  run Proc.new { |env|
    [
      200, 
      {
        'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
        'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=6400' 
      },
      File.open('archive/pages/user.html', File::RDONLY)
    ]
  }
end

# Each map section is repeated for each HTML page served
```

I'd like to simplify this by storing the URL as variable and creating one map section that says

```
map url do
  run Proc.new { |env|
    [
      200, 
      {
        'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
        'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=6400' 
      },
      File.open('archive' + url, File::RDONLY)
    ]
  }
end
```

How can I correctly set this url variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need the map part.

```
run Proc.new { |env|
  [
    200, 
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=6400' 
    },
    File.open( 'archive' + env['PATH_INFO'], File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

Comment: note that this will set the Content-type to 'text/html' for whatever file it finds, even 'robots.txt' or 'favicon.ico'. But I guess you can always leave that line out, and let the browser guess.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
static_page_mappings = {
  '/'                  => 'archive/splash.html',
  '/pages/search.html' => 'archive/pages/search.html'
  '/pages/user.html'   => 'archive/pages/user.html',
}

static_page_mappings.each do |req, file|
  map req do 
    run Proc.new { |env|
      [
        200, 
        {
          'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
          'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=6400',
        },
        File.open(file, File::RDONLY)
      ]
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: See my comment in Eric's post, re Content-type