# a href not working with a bare web page

Tags: ruby, heroku

I've been looking around for a solution to the problem I'm having, but it seems that none of the solutions on SO address my issue.

I was having the dreaded issue where the a href tag in my HTML does not actually take me to the link. At first, I tried removing the JavaScript includes, wondering if something in the JavaScript portion was messing up the page.

Then I removed the CSS portion as well, and ultimately removed everything until the page consisted of simply the header information for the HTML page and only the a href tag. I also changed the link to a non-existent page (to force a 404 error).

When clicking on the link, it keeps me on the current page and doesn't take me to the referenced page (or even give me a 404 error). Following is the stripped out code (everything but the commented out portion):

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>test</title>

    <meta name="description" content="test1" />

    <meta name="keywords" content="test2" />
 </head>

  <a href="test.html">Support</a/>

 </html>
```

Thanks for the help.

---

I made the changes based on the answers given but still see the same behavior. As seen in the screenshot (sorry SO doesn't let me insert images), the URL shows /test.html but the page is still the main page. I changed the text of the link to ensure that the changes were applied.

I'm using rackup to quickly view the changes locally.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saa4n.jpg)

Updated code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>test</title>

    <meta name="description" content="test1" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="test2" />
</head>
<body>
    <a href="test.html">Support2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have extra / at the end - </a/>

Comment: Where are your body tags?

Comment: Ever heard of https://validator.w3.org/ ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently the answer was here:

[How to setup URLs for static site with Ruby Rack on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206289/how-to-setup-urls-for-static-site-with-ruby-rack-on-heroku)

Individual pages were being routed to "/" all the time. Needed to modify "config.ru" to get routing to work properly.

Next step is to look into "sinatra".

Answer (score 0):

**Working and tested:**

> NOTE:  Both files [ current one and test.html ] are in same directory.

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>test</title>

    <meta name="description" content="test1" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="test2" />
 </head>
 <body>
     <a href="test.html">Support</a> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Also test code is working fine using `target="_blank"` in anchor tag , which open link in new page if working fine, like below:

```
<a href="test.html" target="_blank" > support </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra slash in your closing a tag. 
Should be

```
</a>.
```

I would also make sure they are in the same directory.

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, and IE still follow the link for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mzjsyyLt/

Comment: The same works for me. Thanks for correcting that. Could it be something commented out incorrectly in his code that he isn't showing then?

Comment: I've stripped down the code so that it's only the head, and stripped down body. But I still see the same page, even though the URL is different.